# como rellenar un jtable desde sql

Tags: java, sql, java-swing

Tengo una interfaz gráfica que incluye a un jtable, al momento de registrar se ejecuta normal, solo que en el jtable me muestra lo que yo he registrado de forma repetida pero en la base de datos se registra una única vez.

¿Hay alguna manera de solucionarlo de modo de que al momento de que haga un registro se muestre solo una vez en el jtable y guarde a la vez en SQL?

```
try

{

Connection  conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=prueba","sa","sa");

                PreparedStatement statement =conexion.prepareStatement("Insert into datos values (?,?,?)");         
                statement.setString(1,texto1.getText());
                statement.setString(2,texto2.getText());
                statement.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(texto3.getText()));
                statement.executeUpdate();
                //PreparedStatement statement1 =conexion.prepareStatement("Select *from datos");
                 Statement statement1 = conexion.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=statement1.executeQuery("Select nombre,apellido,edad from datos");

                while(rs.next())
                {
                    Object dato[]=new Object[3];

                    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
                     {
                          dato[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);  
                     }
                   modelo.addRow(dato);

                }
                rs.close();

                tabla1.updateUI();



            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia tu consulta por ejemplo: Si la clave principal de la tabla datos fuera auto numérico, la consulta iría asi: "Select nombre, apellido, edad from datos where idDato=(select MAX(idDato) from datos)" Y en lugar de un while debes usar un if. if(rs.next()){ ... }

La mejor opción seria que al ejecutar el guardado de los datos lo asignes a una variable Int. Esto guardara en la variable Int la cantidad de filas insertadas. Seria de esta forma:
int res=statement.executeUpdate();
Y para insertar la fila de datos res debe ser mayor a 0.
if(res>0){

Comment: Gracias me ayudo bastante :)

Answer (score 1):

el problema es que agregas filas a tu JTable cada vez que registras datos, pero se sobreponen sobre las filas que ya tienes agregadas, por eso hay filas repetidas. Puedes eliminar todas las filas del JTable cada vez que insertas datos con el siguiente código:
modelo.setRowCount(0);
Y luego agregar las filas producto de la consulta.
Otra opción seria cambiar la consulta para que te cargue solo los datos que insertaste y así solo insertas al JTable la fila correspondiente a los datos insertados.

Comment: se sigue repitiendo, como podria hacer oara que se cargue solo los datos que inserte ?

Comment: Cambia tu consulta por ejemplo: